# Variable changes on it's own in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have a loop going through an array trying to find which index is a string. It should solve for what that value should be.
I can't figure out why, but as soon as the if statements start `i` becomes 1 which gives my code an error.
I'm not very fluent in C++.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if(auto value = std::get_if<std::string>(&varArr[i])) {
        solvedIndex = i;

        auto value0 = std::get_if<float>(&varArr[0]);
        auto value1 = std::get_if<float>(&varArr[1]);
        auto value2 = std::get_if<float>(&varArr[2]);
        auto value3 = std::get_if<float>(&varArr[3]);

        //i changes to 1 when this if starts??
        if(i = 0) {
            solvedVar = (*value3 / *value1) * *value2;
        } else if (i = 1) {
            solvedVar = *value3 / (*value0 / *value2);
        } else if (i = 2) {
            solvedVar = *value0 / (*value3 / *value1);
        } else {
            solvedVar = *value1 * (*value0 / *value2);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that these variables are declared above. Also, `varArr` is filled with values:

```
std::variant<std::string, float> varArr[4];
int solvedIndex;
float solvedVar;
```

Comment: `if(i = 0)` -> `if(i == 0)` ?? (and the remainder of your conditionals as well -- you are doing assignment, not comparison `:)` In other word `i = 1` sets `i` to `1`, `i == 1` compares if `i` is `1`.

Comment: You need if (i == 0), you are assigning a value to i as well as testing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been noted, in your `if` statements, you are using the assignment operator (`=`) but want the equality comparison operator (`==`). For your variable `i` the first `if` statement sets `i` equal to `0` and `if(0)` is the same as `if(false)`. So your program goes to the first else-if which sets `i` equal to `1` and `if(1)` evaluates to true. Your code then finishes the block within `else if (i = 1) {...}` and then ends.

Answer (score 2):

That's because [operator=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment#Builtin_direct_assignment) is the assignment operator in C++ (and most languages, actually). That changes the value of the variable to the value on the other side. So, for instance:

```
x = 0
```

will change the value of x to 0. Doesn't matter if it's in an if statement. It will always change the value to 0 (or whatever the right hand side value is).

What you are looking for is [operator==](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison), which is the comparison (aka relational) operator in C++/ That asks the question "Are these two things equal?" So, for instance:

```
x == 0
```

asks is x is equal to 0.