# trying to create password in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to do password handling in C++.

For example, I want the password to be 12345678, but no matter what I insert as a meaning of 'a' it always says that the password is correct, so basically it always thinks the quantity of 'a' is equal to the quantity of 'x'.

At the beginning, I tried to do it like this:

```cpp
if (a = 12345678)                                                              
cout << "password is correct";
```

This didn't work either.

here is the picture of the code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zrvy.jpg

Comment: Don''t put pictures of code in the question. Put a [mcve] as text in the question. Btw: `a = 12345678` is assigning `12345678` to `a`, not comparing it for equallity. Use `==`.

Comment: Please try write code here using the adequate format. It is  easier than watch a picture. BTW review the difference between = and ==.

Comment: not everybody can access your link, not everybody can view the image. Questions about code are required to include a [mcve] in the question, if they dont then thats a reason to close the question. I am just telling this so you hopefully understand that Ted actually was trying to help you

Comment: ... i forgot the most important reason: nobody can copy paste your image to compile the code and see what it does (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/why-is-this-program-erroneously-rejected-by-three-c-compilers) for more on that topic)

Comment: @ლუკაალექსაია -- At some places `imgur` links are blocked and/or blacklisted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable changes on it's own in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58253071/variable-changes-on-its-own-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `a = 12345678` is operation that sets `a`to `12345678` and returns `a` by reference. So your if statement simply doesn't do what you want - instead of checking whether `a` is `12345678`, it sets `a` to `12345678` and then checks if `a` isn't zero.

To fix it replace `=` with `==` for comparison.

```
if (a == 12345678)
    cout << "password is correct";
```

Though, it is a bit strange that password is a number and not a string... but whatever.

Comment: oh okay thanks. so if 'a' and 'x' assing to the same number, in this case 12345678 does that mean that they are euqal to each other ?

Comment: okay nevermind i tired and it worked as i wanted <3 thank you a lot :)

Comment: What's strange is that they are storing the password directly and making a hard-coded comparison instead of hashing it and comparing it against the stored hash. I get that is at a "new to C++ and programming" bit of code, but there are better exercises than security theater.